# Using XMLJavaTypeAdapter causes IllegalAnnotationException

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML format with a root element "Blurb" which contains a set of child elements called namespace, each of which has a required attribute "name".  I built some classes with xjc, and it made a Blurb class that contains a List of Namespace objects.

A Hash with the namespace name as the key and the Namespace object as the value seemed handier to me, and I set about making an XMLAdapter.  Using [this blog entry](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) as my guide, I created an adapter class and linked it.  It builds, but when I run it, I get the error, "java.lang.AssertionError: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions".  I've looked up different uses of the XmlJavaTypeAdapter, and they don't seem consistent.  I've tried putting the annotation on the property, the method and both, and all gave me similar errors.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my main class:

```
package com.jolyjonesfamily.blurb.models;

import com.jolyjonesfamily.blurb.map.adapter.BlurbMapAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "pattern",
    "namespace"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "blurb")
public class Blurb {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Cat pattern;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BlurbMapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String, Namespace> namespace;


    // @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BlurbMapAdapter.class)
    public Map<String, Namespace> getNamespace() {
        if (namespace == null) {
            namespace = new HashMap<String, Namespace>();
        }
        return this.namespace;
    }

    public void setNamespace(Map<String, Namespace> namespaceMap) {
        namespace = namespaceMap;
    }

    public Cat getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void setPattern(Cat value) {
        this.pattern = value;
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.jolyjonesfamily.blurb.map.adapter;

import com.jolyjonesfamily.blurb.models.Namespace;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by samjones on 10/19/15.
 */
public class BlurbMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<List<Namespace>, Map<String, Namespace>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Namespace> unmarshal(List<Namespace> namespaceList) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Namespace> namespaceMap = new HashMap<String, Namespace>();
        for(Namespace myNamespace : namespaceList) {
            namespaceMap.put(myNamespace.getName(), myNamespace);
        }
        return namespaceMap;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Namespace> marshal(Map<String, Namespace> namespaceMap) throws Exception {
        List<Namespace> result = new ArrayList<Namespace>();
        result.addAll(namespaceMap.values());
        return result;
    }
}
```

If it's important, here's my Namespace class:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2015.10.07 at 09:29:23 PM CDT 
//


package com.jolyjonesfamily.blurb.models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{}category" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="name" use="required" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anySimpleType" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "category"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "namespace")
public class Namespace {

    protected List<Category> category;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected String name;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the category property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the category property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getCategory().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Category }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Category> getCategory() {
        if (category == null) {
            category = new ArrayList<Category>();
        }
        return this.category;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the name property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setName(String value) {
        this.name = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, I have a likely theory.  I think you can't use an adapter to adapt a List of Objects to something.  Instead, you have to have that list live in another object, and you can adapt that.

In this case, that means that I have another class "Namespaces" that contains the list.  I make an adapter that converts Namespaces to a hash of String, Namespace and everything's happy.  Only, I don't like making that class, so let me know if you know a way I can do it without this list.  [this blog post](https://www.tomasmalmsten.com/2012/05/unmarshall-marshall-java-maps-xml-jaxb/) is my source.